# Step functions input to glue job

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine which will be triggered by event bridge as soon as an object is uploaded to s3 bucket. The stat machine will first call a lambda function to validate the input file and then returns a result set like this

```json
result = {
             "statusCode": statusCode,
             "bucket_name": bucket,
             "key_name": key
         }
```

The next state is a choice state where if the status code is 200 then it starts glue crawler and then get crawler and then glue start job run for transformations on input file.The gluestart job run should take the bucket name and key as arguments to glue start job run.
here is the step function json workflow

```json
{
  "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
  "States": {
    "Lambda Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "ResultPath": "$.result",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:877016640395:function:my_lambda:$LATEST",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 1,
          "MaxAttempts": 3,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Choice",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "statusCode.$": "$.Payload.statusCode",
        "bucket_name.$": "$.Payload.bucket_name",
        "key_name.$": "$.Payload.key_name"
      }
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.result.statusCode",
          "NumericEquals": 200,
          "Next": "StartCrawler"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.result.statusCode",
          "NumericEquals": 300,
          "Next": "SNS Publish"
        }
      ]
    },
    "SNS Publish": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
      "Parameters": {
        "Message.$": "$",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:877016640395:snstopic.fifo"
      },
      "Next": "Fail"
    },
    "Fail": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    },
    "StartCrawler": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "crawler-1"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler",
      "Next": "GetCrawler"
    },
    "GetCrawler": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "crawler-1"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
      "Next": "Choice (1)"
    },
    "Choice (1)": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
          "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
          "Next": "Wait"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "PassStateToGlueETL"
    },
    "PassStateToGlueETL": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "statusCode.$": "$.Payload.statusCode",
        "bucket_name.$": "$.Payload.bucket_name",
        "key_name.$": "$.Payload.key_name"
      },
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.result",
      "Next": "Glue StartJobRun"
    },
    "Glue StartJobRun": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "fx-transform",
        "Arguments": {
          "bucket.$": "$.result.bucket_name",
          "key.$": "$.result.key_name"
        }
      },
      "Next": "StartCrawler (1)"
    },
    "StartCrawler (1)": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "crawler-1"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:startCrawler",
      "Next": "GetCrawler (1)"
    },
    "GetCrawler (1)": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Name": "crawler-1"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:glue:getCrawler",
      "Next": "Choice (2)"
    },
    "Choice (2)": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Crawler.State",
          "StringEquals": "RUNNING",
          "Next": "Wait (1)"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "CopyObject"
    },
    "CopyObject": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Parameters": {
        "Bucket": "test-bucket-1943-19",
        "CopySource": "processed/input_FW.txt",
        "Key": "archived/input_FW.txt"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:copyObject",
      "Next": "DeleteObject"
    },
    "DeleteObject": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "Bucket": "test-bucket-1943-19",
        "Key": "processed/input_FW.txt"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:deleteObject"
    },
    "Wait (1)": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 5,
      "Next": "GetCrawler (1)"
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 5,
      "Next": "GetCrawler"
    }
  }
}
```

can you help me pass the output of lambda to glue start job run so that I will pass the arguments and continue my processing?